# how to get the data back from the page ajax jquery

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I am using the following code. Which is posting fine to a page. But now I need the data back from the posted `password.php` page. How would I get that data back?

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: password.php',
    data: 'newPassword=' + password + '&userID=<?php print $userID; ?>',
    success: function(success) {
        if(success == 1) {
            $("#Pass").html('The password has been reset.  The temporary password is: <font color=red><b>' +password+'</b></font>'); 
        } else {
            $("#Pass").html('There was an error processing your request. The password was not reset.'); 
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Which data? Is your posted code not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already got it there in the "success" variable of your anonymous function, sort of.

Eg., assuming password.php just returns a string containing the new password, here's the code I think you're looking for:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: password.php',
    data: 'newPassword=' + password + '&userID=<?php print $userID; ?>',
    success: function(data) {
        $("#Pass").html('The password has been reset.  The temporary password is: <font color=red><b>' + data +'</b></font>');
    },
    error: function(obj, status, e) {
        $("#Pass").html('There was an error processing your request. The password was not reset. The error was: ' + status);
    })
});
```

Take a look at the jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/. The success function is called on success, and the error function will be called if the request isn't successful.

Answer (score 1):

`success` is the data. You have to first find out what it is before you decide what you want to do with it. It can be a JSON object or an HTML string.

`alert( typeof success)` and `alert( success.length)` if its a string, and do checks and then decide what you want to do with it.

I suggest using JSON for the password.php page, so the response is divided up instead of being an html string which most likely is the case here.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're echoing in your php server side code.

```
echo $email;
```

not

```
return $email;
```